# What values should I send to normalized view matrix so a tilemap scrolling only spans a tile?

Tags: opengl, matrix, scroll, view, 2d

This is the code that produces the projection, view and model matrices that get sent to the shader:

```
    GL.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND)
    GL.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)    

    arguments['texture'].bind()

    arguments['shader'].bind()
    arguments['shader'].uniformi('u_Texture', arguments['texture'].slot)

    proj = glm.ortho(0.0, float(arguments['screenWidth']), 0.0, float(arguments['screenHeight']), -1.0, 1.0)

    arguments['cameraXOffset'] = (float(arguments['cameraXOffset']) / 32) / float(arguments['screenWidth'])
    arguments['cameraYOffset'] = (- float(arguments['cameraYOffset']) / 32) / float(arguments['screenHeight'])

    print('{}, {}'.format(arguments['cameraXOffset'], arguments['cameraYOffset']))

    view = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1.0), glm.vec3(float(arguments['cameraXOffset']), float(arguments['cameraYOffset']), 0.0))

    model = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1.0), glm.vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_Proj', proj)
    arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_View', view)
    arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_Model', model)
```

The projection matrix goes from 0.0 to screen width, and from 0.0 to screen height. That allows me to use the actual width in pixels of the tiles (32x32) when determining the vertex floats. Also, when the user presses the wasd keys, the camera accumulates offsets that span the width or height of a tile (always 32). Unfortunately, to reflect that offset in the view matrix, it seems that I need to normalize it, and I can't figure out how to do it so a single movement in any cardinal direction spans a single tile and nothing more. It constantly accumulates an error, so at the end of the map in any direction it shows a band of background (white in this case, for now).

This is the most important part that determines how much it will scroll with the given camera offsets:

```
    arguments['cameraXOffset'] = (float(arguments['cameraXOffset']) / 32) / float(arguments['screenWidth'])
    arguments['cameraYOffset'] = (- float(arguments['cameraYOffset']) / 32) / float(arguments['screenHeight'])
```

Can any of you figure out if that "normalization" for the sake of the view matrix is correct? Or is this a rounding issue? In that case, could I solve it somehow?

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color; 
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 v_Color;
out vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 u_Proj;
uniform mat4 u_View;
uniform mat4 u_Model;

void main()
{ 
    gl_Position = u_Model * u_View * u_Proj * vec4(position, 1.0);
    v_TexCoord = texCoord; v_Color = color;
}
```

---

FINAL VERSION:
Solved. As mentioned by the commenter, had to change this line in the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = u_Model * u_View * u_Proj * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

to:

```
gl_Position = u_Proj * u_View * u_Model * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

The final version of the code, that finally allows the user to scroll exactly one tile over:

```
arguments['texture'].bind()

arguments['shader'].bind()
arguments['shader'].uniformi('u_Texture', arguments['texture'].slot)

proj = glm.ortho(0.0, float(arguments['screenWidth']), 0.0, float(arguments['screenHeight']), -1.0, 1.0)

arguments['cameraXOffset'] = (float(arguments['cameraXOffset']) / 32) / arguments['screenWidth']
arguments['cameraYOffset'] = (float(-arguments['cameraYOffset']) / 32) / arguments['screenHeight']

view = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1.0), glm.vec3(float(arguments['cameraXOffset']), float(arguments['cameraYOffset']), 0.0))

 model = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1.0), glm.vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

 arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_Proj', proj)
 arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_View', view)
 arguments['shader'].uniform_matrixf('u_Model', model)
```

Comment: What is `cameraXOffset` and `cameraYOffset`? Are these the indices of the tiles?

Comment: No. If the user presses the "a" or "d" key, the cameraXOffset gets either 32.0 added or substracted, which is the width of the tiles. That is used to move the map either left or right. Same with "w" or "s" for the cameraYOffset, but up or down in that case. Those offsets should be normalized in some way in order to feed them to the view matrix so the map will move in one of the four directions but just exactly one tile. As I mentioned, I can't figure out how to calculate the value for the view matrix so each time you move the map it just moves a tile over and not a tile and a few pixels more.

Comment: If `cameraXOffset` and  `cameraYOffset` are divisible by 32 then you need not any "normalization" and it should work fine.

Comment: If I pass a camera offset that is a multiple of 32 to the view matrix, when the final model view projection matrix gets multiplied in the shader, the displacement is so big that the whole screen shows the background. The map only moves a bit when the values fed to the view matrix are less than 1.0, which is what I mean by needing to be normalized. However, the issue is that the current calculations move the map more than a tile over (like a tile and a few pixels), so by the time you reach the other end of the map, there's a strip of background where it should just show the last tile.

Comment: *"If I pass a camera offset that is a multiple of 32 to the view matrix, when the final model view projection matrix gets multiplied in the shader, the displacement is so big that the whole screen shows the background."* If that is the case, the you don't apply the orthographic projection matrix as specified in the question.

Comment: What does the vertex shader do?

Comment: The relevant line of the vertex shader: "gl_Position = u_Model * u_View * u_Proj * vec4(position, 1.0);"

All it does is multiply the matrices with the vertex position set before. The vertex positions are also multiples of 32, given that the orthographic projection matrix set allows it. However, as I mentioned, the view matrix doesn't seem to play by the rules of the orthographic projection, which is throwing the whole thing off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flip the order of the matrices when you transform the vertex coordinate to the clip space coordinate:

```
gl_Position = u_Proj * u_View * u_Model * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

---

See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

> Furthermore, the *-operator can be used for matrix-vector products of the corresponding dimension, e.g.:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = m * v; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 3. * 20., 2. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```
>
> Note that the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right.
>
> If a vector is multiplied to a matrix from the left, the result corresponds to to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right. This corresponds to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right:
>   Thus, multiplying a vector from the left to a matrix corresponds to multiplying it from the right to the transposed matrix:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = v * m; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 2. * 20., 3. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```

This also applies to the matrix multiplication itself. The first matrix which has to be applied to the vector, has to be the most right matrix and the last matrix the most left, in the row of concatenated matrices.

Comment: That definitely changed things, although by passing now the camera offsets, which are multiples of 32, to the view matrix, the map moves exactly two tiles over. The logical thing, that I tried, is dividing the offsets by two and then passing them to the view matrix, but that makes them move a tile and a half over. I'm tinkering with the calculations.